# Embed Powerpoint in web page without conversion as per Confluence

Tags: web, powerpoint, embedded-resource, confluence

Confluence automatically shows Powerpoint slideshows without any conversion you just use a built in one line macro and it shows up embedded in the page using a Flash solution.

I've tried searching extensively but everywhere tells me I need to convert to some other format or host on Google Docs or Youtube etc.

Can someone suggest to me another Flash based solution where I don't need to convert from PPT first or tell me which one Confluence uses (I have also tried to find this myself)?

Comment: Perhaps Confluence invested a few hundred thousand dollars into programmers to write the tool themselves and kept it closed source for business reasons?

Comment: @sarnold - And your comment helps answer my question how? High rep users should know better than wasting space with idle speculation. Microsoft spent millions of dollars investing in IE and Windows. But there is still Ubuntu and Firefox.

Comment: I'm just addressing the final point: _tell me which one Confluence uses (I have also tried to find this myself)_.

Comment: @sarnold - But you actually _aren't_ addressing my final point. You are just speculating which is not helpful.

Comment: Which is why it's just a comment. I'm hoping someone else will notice the un-answered question and provide you with something _useful_. :)

Comment: If the result is embedded as Flash, *some* conversion must be taking place.  PowerPoint is neither flash based nor can it save as Flash on its own.  Perhaps a better question would be:  "How can PowerPoint be converted into Flash for use in a web page?"  There are several products that address this.  Articulate is a well-respected one but there are others.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - Confluence does this on the fly. The solutions you are proposing require me to convert first the embed as a flash file.

Comment: Have you checked with the various vendors to see whether they have a way of incorporating their process into your solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not feasible to view or create a slideshow of the PowerPoint slides on a web page without converting them to images. You can convert the slides to the required image format. The output format will depend upon your particular scenario i.e. whether you want to show high quality and scalable output or you want to show low quality and low size output. You may then create a slide show from those images even using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Find information about embedding a PowerPoint slide at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Embedding+PowerPoint+Presentations+in+a+Page

The View File macro may be the one you're looking for:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/View+File+Macro

```
    {viewfile:ExampleFileName.ppt}
```

Answer (score 0):

The results are much better if you export to PDF from PowerPoint then use the Confluence macro for PDF.

Answer (score 0):

This tool turns confluence into powerpoint https://bigpresentation.bigquant.com/ , conflucne + reveal js.

[image: p1]

[image: p2]